# netbeans platform-auto update plugin

Tags: netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

In our netbeans platform application, we are opening the tool by triggering the .BAT file. We have used netbeans befault plugins module for updates. This plugin makes use of "Auto Update Services" and "Auto Update UI" modules. We want to customize the "restart" feature in this. That means we want to call our .BAT file on restart after the plugin update is done.  I am quiet new to netbeans platform. Looking for some suggestions on this.